# Automatically select lags for AutoRegression model statsmodels

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, autoregressive-models

In `statsmodels v0.10.1` there was no need to choose the number of lags in [Autoregressive AR(p) model](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AR.html). If you chose not to specify the number of lags, the model would have chosen the best one for you which was ideal for running the model automatically. In the new version `0.11.1` this model is now called [AutoReg](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AutoReg.html?highlight=statsmodels%20tsa%20autoreg), and it seems that the lags are now mandatory. Is there a way to make this model in the new version choose the best number of lags for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is now a standalone function, `statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.ar_select_order`

https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.ar_select_order.html?highlight=ar_select

Comment: If I understand it correctly, `statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.ar_select_order` gives the best lags ordered as an array where the first is the best one? in the last example in the docs (you linked), the result is `array([1, 2, 9])`, does it mean that for that specific data the best number of lags for the AR model is 1?

Comment: That means that if you go what is called a global search that considers all lag combinations that include any lag between 1 and 12, but not necessarily all contiguous lags, then the best combination of lags, according to the IC, is 1, 2 and 9. In other toyes, the best model is a restricted AR(9):

Y_t = c_0 + c_1 Y_{t-1} + c_2 Y_{t-2} + c_9 Y_{t-9} + \epsilon_t

If you want a standard AR(p) that includes all lags 1, 2, .., p, then leave `glob=False`.

Comment: In that example, (`array([1, 2, 9])`) does that mean that to predict the next data point we need to use the data from points 1,2, and 9? In other words, for that specific problem, the best regression combination is to use the last point, the one before the last, and the 9th before the last?

Comment: Suppose you have data for y0, y1, ..., y99, so 100 points, and want to predict y100. The "optimal" model, as selected by this method, would use observation y(100-1), y(100-2) and y(100-9), or y99, y98 and y91. So yes.