# Correctly interpreting statsmodels.tsa.ar_models.ar_select_order function array to determine optimal lag

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, autoregressive-models

Using statsmodels 0.12.0 I am attempting to determine the optimal lag for a `statsmodels.tsa.ar_models.AutoReg` model. I am using US population data with monthly timesteps and passing in a maximum lag of 12 to the `statsmodels.tsa.ar_models.ar_select_order` object to evaluate.

```
from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AutoReg, ar_select_order    
df = pd.read_csv('Data\uspopulation.csv', index_col='DATE', parse_dates=True)
df.index.freq = 'MS'
train_data = df.iloc[:84]
test_data = df.iloc[84:]
modelp = ar_select_order(train_data['PopEst'], maxlag=12)
```

The code above returns a numpy array of `[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12]`, which I am interpreting as "The optimal lag *p* is 12" as per this StackOverflow question: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63048832/automatically-select-lags-for-autoregression-model-statsmodels). However, evaluating on some metrics (RMSE) I find that my AutoReg fitted models with `maxlag=12` are performing worse than lower order models. By trial and error I found that the optimal lag is 8. So I am having difficulty interpreting the resulting numpy array, I have been reading the resources on [statsmodels.com/ar_select_order](https://www.statsmodels.org/v0.12.0/generated/statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.ar_select_order.html?highlight=ar_select_order) and [statsmodels.com/autoregressions](https://www.statsmodels.org/v0.12.0/examples/notebooks/generated/autoregressions.html?highlight=ar_select_order) but they have not made it clearer.

Does anyone here have any input? New to this python library and felling a bit lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The code above returns a numpy array of [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12], which I am interpreting as "The optimal lag p is 12" as per this StackOverflow question: stackoverflow.

Yes, that's right. The reason it returns an array instead of just `12` is that it can also search for models that do not include all of the lags, if you set `glob=True`. For example `[ 1  2  3 12]` might be a common result for a monthly model that has some annual seasonal pattern.

> However, evaluating on some metrics (RMSE) I find that my AutoReg fitted models with maxlag=12 are performing worse than lower order models. By trial and error I found that the optimal lag is 8. So I am having difficulty interpreting the resulting numpy array, I have been reading the resources on statsmodels.com/ar_select_order and statsmodels.com/autoregressions but they have not made it clearer.

This function is returning the model that is judged optimal using [information criteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_selection#Criteria). In particular, the default is [BIC or Bayesian information criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion). If you use other criteria, such as minimizing the out-of-sample RSME, then it is definitely possible to find that a different model is judged to be optimal.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense! I definitely need to read up on the theory of information criteria. I have been following an online course that uses  statsmodels 0.9.0 statsmodels.tsa.ar_models.AR and tried to recreate the automatic optimal lags that the AR.fit() could calculate when leaving maxlag undefined, using ar_select_order 0.12.0. I see now that ar_select_order is not analogous to the function of AR.fit() lag selection. 
Instead I ended up creating a for-loop that evaluates on RMSE with out-of-sample data.
Thank you very much for the clarification!